# Show the edited form of the question when I've approved it

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

## Current Behavior

When a low-rep user proposes an edit, they see the question in its edited form even before their edit is approved.

When I vote to approve an edit (first vote), I **do not** see the edit I voted to approve.

[image]

## Proposed Behavior

I would like to propose that when a user expresses their support for an edit by voting to approve it, that user then sees the edit as if they were the user that proposed it*.

When I approve an edit, that locks me out of editing the post, so until the edit is fully approved, I can only see the poorly formatted (usually) version. I would like to be able to see the edited version as soon as I signify that I approve of the edit.

<sub>*This would appear similar to the low-rep user's view, where I believe it is marked somewhere as a pending edit.</sub>

Comment: Related discussion asking for an explanation of current behavior, but not proposing a specific change, like here:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125909/why-dont-pending-edits-i-approve-show-for-me

Comment: @Laura Is this feature being given any consideration? It's one of the more frustrating things about approving edits in-situ.

Comment: Dupe on [SO]: [Can edits we approve be displayed to us?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288719/2157640)

Answer (score 20):

I've needed this a lot. Full support.

The only change that i propose is to show a banner similar to what <2k users see, to inform you that the edit hasn't taken place yet.

Answer (score 3):

I fully agree this should be visible, but then to everybody (maybe in a separate tab to avoid confusion and you can see both the original and edited version).

Why? Because it is quite unfair, if you and I get a readable post, and a low rep user doesn't. In fact this is already the case for the edit button which goes to the review item. You could take advantage from that.

So I suggest to make the edit 'public information'.

Comment: There's good and bad in your proposal. If it's a good edit, showing it immediately is obviously all to the good. If it isn't though, it shouldn't be shown to anyone. Which leaves only showing it to those who approve it (suggester and accepters), until it gets approved or rejected. And if there are two potentially best versions of the post, the current top-revision and the pending suggestion, while we could allow anonymous and low-rep users to see them both, that would clutter the user-interface and lead to onfusion, especially as they cannot fully act on it.